# Ruby undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to learn ruby, i have this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

randomNumber = 5

class Testing
  def self.add
      puts randomNumber * 6
  end
end

Testing.add
```

And i get the error "Undefined local variable or method 'randomNumber'... But i have defined it .. so i thought, with the randomNumber = 5 ..  i've tried int randomNumber = 5 but still no help.  I have a feeling my oop sucks and i need to do more reading but i just don't get why this isn't working.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Why would you think *randomNumber* is in scope for the Testing class?

Comment: @CodeGnome because he's obviously coming from JavaScript. Look at the naming conventions too.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't work like javascript

```
class Testing

  # define a class variable
  @@random_number = 5

  # "add" class method
  def self.add
    puts @@random_number * 6
  end
end
```

Comment: My bad, it is `$` isn't it :P Never used global variables in Ruby.

Comment: This isn't a global variable ! It's a class variable !

Comment: why not use a class instance variable (`@`) over a class variable (`@@`)? or a constant (screaming_snake_case)?

Comment: @astreal Because class variables are entirely appropriate for this case and are easier to use.